# Проблема при запуске NGINX + Phusion Passenger. Никак не хочет запуститься. 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Пытаюсь запустить их, но мне выдает

```
403 Forbidden
```

Настройки NGINX:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name localhost;

location / {
            passenger_enabled on;
            root /var/www/rails_app_folder/public;
    }

chmod -R 777 rails_app_folder #тоже не помог
```

Что я делаю не так??? Порылся уже во всех форумах, испытал все, но не помогает ничего. Буду премного благодарен помощи!

Comment: А в логах что?

Answer (score 1):

У меня была проблем,а что не было swap на сервере, **лечится**:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
mkswap /swap
swapon /swap
```

**Пример:**

```
gem install passenger --version 4.0.16
```

или

```
gem 'passenger', '~> 4.0.16'
```

**Далее:**

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

**Далее правим /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf :**

*passenger_root, passenger_ruby* прописываем актуальные (видно из настройки *passenger-install-nginx-module*)

```
http {
…
passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/passenger-4.0.16;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/ruby;
…
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name www.yourhost.com;
root /somewhere/public;
passenger_enabled on;
}
```